# Protractor can't see the file just downloaded into the folder

Tags: protractor

```
// gives count of downloads in download folder.
this.getCountOfDownloads = function (fileName,elementToClick) {

    //provides a way to look for filenames matching a certain pattern (in the worst case, you can wait for the *.* - basically, any file to appear)
    var glob = require("glob");
    var filesArray = glob.sync("./src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads/"+"*.xlsx");

    console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);

    browser.driver.wait(function () {
        elementToClick.click();//to download

        if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
            // this check is necessary because `glob.sync` can return
            // an empty list, which will be considered as a valid output
            // making the wait to end.

            return filesArray;
        }
    }, 4444).then(function (filesArray) {
        console.log("sizee",filesArray[0]);



        // now we have the filename and can do whatever we want
    });
    browser.sleep(5555); console.log("sizee",filesArray.length);
};
```

`elemtclick` downloads file.

I can see in `intelj` when I click `sync` button.

At first it is empty. Then I run this and it shows size as 0 at both console output. Then in next run, it becomes 1 because the file downloaded before. `filesarray> 0` is not becoming true.

I put `browser.sleep()` after `element.click()` but it still does not wait for file or does not sync with it.

What I want to do is:

- I get the counts of downloading before the operation
- I get the counts after downloaded
- I expect `count = currentcount - 1`

But it cannot see the file, why?

I think I have to refresh the session but maybe there is an another way.

Answer (score 3):

Your click (and download) is after the `glob.sync()`.

After the download, you need to do another `glob.sync()` to read the new state of the directory.